# Upgrade Moodledata from 1.9 to 2.2

Tags: php, upgrade, moodle

I have a custom module in Moodle 1.9  I have to update it to 2.2.  The problem is the Moodledata I have some file to be stored in moodledata and that has to be converted to 2.2 and I dont know how exactly to do it.  In 2.2 the files are stored with some reference in database.  Also I am not able to access files using the files.php.

Any one please give me step by step how to change the files accessing code and how to upgrade the moodledata to 2.2.  Please help.

I lost more than a week searching for a solution in internet.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Did you read the documentation on how to upgrade from 1.9 to 2.2?](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Upgrading_to_Moodle_2.2)

Comment: Thanks Matt.. I looked at that also.  I fixed all the coding issues.  The moodledata is the only issue remaining.  that is reading and writing of old files.

Answer (score 0):

when you upgrade from Moodle 1.9 to 2.2 the upgrade script will automatically index the files in your moodledata folder and store a reference to them in the Moodle db. You don't have to do any manual processing of files as part of this process. The update script will take care of this for you. The script will take a long time to run on large Moodle sites.